# Migrate a .net CF 2.0 app from WM 5.0 to WEH 6.5 - Can I use xamarin in this situation

Tags: xamarin

I have a .net CF 2.0 application(app also uses some C++ libraries), running on a windows mobile 5.0 device. And we are planning to use a new device in Windows Embedded 6.5.
Here can I use Xamarin studio to port my app from .netCF 2.0 ?
So that along with device upgrade I will have our app code-base platform independent.
Pros/Cons/thoughts ?

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin only supports Windows 8 (plus 8.1 and 10 runtime coming soon) - not WEH 6.5

If you are looking to transfer to Windows 8 and you are looking to just click the app and hope it ports to Xamarin that isn't going to happen.

If you are coming from WM5 on Compact Framework, its not going to be a nice port. I would recommend a write from scratch and build again. Copy and paste code sections as necessary but it is certainly a build the projects and views from scratch.

You might get some good reuse out of copying C# code across depending how extensive that is, but if it is tied to platform specifics you will run into many issues.

Remember you are going from CF 2.0 to PCL. From WM5 to Windows 8. They are very different.

Also those C++ libraries may have significant problems if they are WM5 specific.